# Cheap or free hosting for single file to access from iOS app

Tags: ios, hosting, google-docs, dropbox

I need to have a very small file stored somewhere to update a list dynamically on an iOS app that I am building. Is there a hosting solution for someplace like this, just a single file that can be updated regularly by me and yet still dynamically populate the iOS app? Would dropbox work for something like this? Or Google Docs?

UPDATE *
Just so as to explain a little better. I needed to know for certain if Dropbox was up to handling a task like this (with multiple requests and such) or if there was an established alternative.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this got a downvote so I can update it

Comment: I think it's because your question seems quite off topic. I don't think so but some people maybe think it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using dropbox. You just store your list file in the public folder of your dropbox and access it from there.